Problem with Javascript ParentNode - Div containers
There is a problem with parentnodes divs, and I really don't know what I'm doing wrong
I have tried different things but I can't get it to display correctly, and the console always gives me the same error:
Uncaught DOMException: Node.insertBefore: Child to insert before is not a child of this node
processNode ...
EventListener.handleEvent* 

I would appreciate the help of someone more experienced than me to try to solve this problem.
The result should be: (a div class inside another div)
<div class="embed">
    <div class="embed-player">theplayer embed HERE</div>
</div>

But what I get is: (a div below another div)
The script:
    <script>
...
                    var embedDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    embedDiv.className = 'embed';
                    var embedId = 'embed-player';
                    embedDiv.id = embedId;
                    parent.insertBefore(before, node);
                    parent.insertBefore(embedDiv, node);
                    var after = document.createTextNode(text.slice(regex.lastIndex));
                    parent.insertBefore(after, node);
                    parent.removeChild(node);
                    var script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.innerHTML = `theplayer.embed('` + embedId + `', '` + match[1] + `',{locale: "auto", autoplay: true});`;
                    parent.insertBefore(script, after);
                }
            } else if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
                    processNode(node.childNodes[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        processNode(document.body);
    });
...
    </script>


I made a snippet. It gives error - please correct the script

When you were asked to "correct the script" of the snippet, we wanted you to make your question more useful and more easily debugged. This is your question, you have every right to edit as you wish (other than vandalism), but making your question less useful, less easily answered and debugged seems counterproductive. If you would like to be helped, please rollback the edits and correct the script as originally asked. If not, that's absolutely fine but you'll limit the number of people willing to help.

Few mistakes in your code:

expectation:

<div class="ipcl-embed">
   <div class="ipcl-embed-player">
   </div>
</div>

but code:
                    var embedDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    embedDiv.className = 'ipcl-embed';
                    var embedId = 'ipcl-embed-player';//assigning this id to same div which has class ipcl-embed? instead of child?
                    embedDiv.id = embedId;


you should create another div within .ipcl-embed i.e..ipcl-embed-player append it then handle script
handle node insertion in proper order

Edited script:
<script>
                    var embedDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    embedDiv.className = 'ipcl-embed';
                    
                    var playerDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    playerDiv.className = 'ipcl-embed-player';
                    embedDiv.appendChild(playerDiv);

                    
                    parent.insertBefore(embedDiv, node);// Insert the embedDiv before the text node (node)
                    parent.removeChild(node);// Remove the original text node


                    var script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.innerHTML = `theplayer.embed('` + playerDiv.className + `', '` + match[1] + `', {locale: "auto", autoplay: true});`;
                    parent.appendChild(script);
                }

            } else if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
                    processNode(node.childNodes[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        processNode(document.body);
    });
</script>


Thank you to help me to understand which was the error
